# Ghost blog get featured posts on single post page

Tags: ghost-blog

I want to show featured posts on sidebar, and I code like this:

```
{{#foreach posts}}
  {{#if featured}}
      <!-- do something -->
  {{/if}}
{{/foreach}}
```

This works well for me on homepage, but when I turn to single post page it's broken.

Seeming that I can't use {{#posts}} on single post page?

Comment: Correct, the #posts object is only available on index pages: http://themes.ghost.org/v0.5.5/docs/structure#context-table. There are multiple posts in the forums about ways to add a posts feed to a sidebar, but they all involve javascript. Ex: https://ghost.org/forum/plugins/4877-latests-posts/

Comment: Finally I use ajax to get featured posts that are showed on homepage. I would be glad to see if here's some way to do this on the server side :).